# How to escape special characters in Vim/FuzzyFinder?

Tags: vim, escaping, fuzzyfinder

I am using the line search of FuzzyFinder in Vim. I am trying to find lines that contains two asterisks (**). Obviously asteriks are use for pattern matching so I tried backslash escaping, but that doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: What backslash escaping did you try?

Comment: Can you write your command? and sample of what you need to find?

Comment: I used the '\' to escape the asteriks. Basically I wrote comments on a long configuration file, e.g. // ******** SECTION **********, what I am trying to do is finding all the sections with the line search of FuzzyFinder. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't search for literal `*`; you have to search for different characters to get your results. FuzzyFinder is a general-purpose engine, and in most modes, the use of `*` as a wildcard is both intuitive and without problems. With line search, there's this corner case you've encountered. Too bad.